# Яндекс Расписание API в чем ошибка? Как исправить, помогите пожалуйста?

Tags: php, html, json, яндекс-расписания

Есть код:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v1.0/schedule/?apikey=token&format=json&uid=038AA_tis&station=s9616993&lang=ru&thread=false");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json=json_decode($response,true);
?>
<?php 
$products=json_decode($response,true);

foreach ($products as $key => $value) { 
    echo "<table class='mytable'>";
      foreach ($value as $k=> $v) {
           echo "<tr><td><br>".$k."</td><td></td></tr>";
           foreach ($v as $g=> $l) { 
               $g=str_replace ('except_days','Кроме дней:',$g);
               $g=str_replace ('uid','Идентификатор:',$g);
                $g=str_replace ('start_time','Время начала:',$g);
               $g=str_replace ('title','город прибытия:',$g);
                $g=str_replace ('short_title','Направление:',$g);
                 $g=str_replace ('departure_time','Время отъезда:',$g);

                     $g=str_replace ('platform','Платформа:',$g);
                     $g=str_replace ('arrival_time','Время прибытия:',$g);
                     $g=str_replace ('days','По дням:',$g);
                     $g=str_replace ('is_fuzzy','',$g);
                     $g=str_replace ('stops','Остановки:',$g);

                       $g=str_replace ('terminal','терминал:',$g);
             $g=str_replace ('thread','Шаг:',$g);
                     echo "<tr><td>".$g."</td><td>".$l."</td></tr>";
            } 
     }
     echo "</table>";  
}

?>
```

Не получается вывести все значения.
Вот ответ Json

```
{"date":null,"pagination":{"has_next":false,"per_page":100,"page_count":1,"total":5,"page":1},"station":{"code":"s9616993","station_type":"вокзал","title":"Керчь","popular_title":"","short_title":"","transport_type":"train","type":"station"},"event":"departure","schedule":[{"except_days":null,"thread":{"carrier":{"code":8459,"codes":{"icao":null,"sirena":null,"iata":null},"title":"ГУП РК \"Крымская железная дорога\""},"transport_type":"suburban","uid":"6746_0_9616993_g16_4","title":"Керчь - Джанкой","vehicle":null,"number":"6746","short_title":"Керчь - Джанкой","express_type":null},"platform":"","arrival_time":null,"days":"ежедневно","stops":"кроме: 57 км","terminal":null,"is_fuzzy":false,"departure_time":"08:20"},{"except_days":null,"thread":{"carrier":{"code":8459,"codes":{"icao":null,"sirena":null,"iata":null},"title":"ГУП РК \"Крымская железная дорога\""},"transport_type":"train","uid":"562S_0_2","title":"Ростов-на-Дону - Симферополь","vehicle":null,"number":"562С","short_title":"Ростов-на-Дону - Симферополь","express_type":null},"platform":"","arrival_time":"10:30","days":"по чётным по 30.01","stops":"","terminal":null,"is_fuzzy":false,"departure_time":"10:35"},{"except_days":null,"thread":{"carrier":{"code":8459,"codes":{"icao":null,"sirena":null,"iata":null},"title":"ГУП РК \"Крымская железная дорога\""},"transport_type":"suburban","uid":"6742_0_9616993_g16_4","title":"Керчь - Джанкой","vehicle":null,"number":"6742","short_title":"Керчь - Джанкой","express_type":null},"platform":"","arrival_time":null,"days":"ежедневно","stops":"кроме: 57 км","terminal":null,"is_fuzzy":false,"departure_time":"14:20"},{"except_days":null,"thread":{"carrier":{"code":8459,"codes":{"icao":null,"sirena":null,"iata":null},"title":"ГУП РК \"Крымская железная дорога\""},"transport_type":"train","uid":"562YE_0_2","title":"Симферополь - Ростов-на-Дону","vehicle":null,"number":"562Э","short_title":"Симферополь - Ростов-на-Дону","express_type":null},"platform":"","arrival_time":"16:08","days":"по чётным по 30.01","stops":"","terminal":null,"is_fuzzy":false,"departure_time":"16:13"},{"except_days":null,"thread":{"carrier":{"code":8459,"codes":{"icao":null,"sirena":null,"iata":null},"title":"ГУП РК \"Крымская железная дорога\""},"transport_type":"suburban","uid":"6744_0_9616993_g16_4","title":"Керчь - Джанкой","vehicle":null,"number":"6744","short_title":"Керчь - Джанкой","express_type":null},"platform":"","arrival_time":null,"days":"ежедневно","stops":"кроме: 57 км, 13 км","terminal":null,"is_fuzzy":false,"departure_time":"20:45"}]}
```

Мне нужно получить значения:

> except_days, title, short_title, departure_time, arrival_time, days,
>   stops,

Остальные при этом чтобы не появлялись.
Помогите поправить код, чтобы левые данные не вылазили, а те которые показал высвечивались. Уже голову всю сломал. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Может проще не проходить в цикле все ключи и значения, а вручную взять именно те значения, которые нужны?

Comment: Именно такая задача и стоит, как переделать скрипт я не знаю и путаюсь в путях к классам в json. В этом и заключается моя проблема.

Comment: Мой совет, как минимум, написать `echo '<pre>';
print_r($products);
echo '</pre>';` чтоб четко представлять структуру данного массива

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ, с ручным указанием имен полей и значений

```
<style>
    .mytable {
        margin: 10px;
    }
    table, tr, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>

<?php 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v1.0/schedule/?apikey=token&format=json&uid=038AA_tis&station=s9616993&lang=ru&thread=false");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $json=json_decode($response,true);
    $products=json_decode($response,true);
?>

<?php foreach ($products['schedule'] as $schedule): ?>
    <table class="mytable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Кроме дней
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $schedule['except_days'] ? $schedule['except_days'] : 'Не указано'; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>     
        <tr>
            <td>
                Город прибытия
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $schedule['thread']['title']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Направление
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $schedule['thread']['short_title']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Время отъезда
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $schedule['departure_time']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Время прибытия
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $schedule['arrival_time'] ? $schedule['arrival_time'] : 'Не указано'; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                По дням
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $schedule['days']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Остановки
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $schedule['stops'] ? $schedule['stops'] : 'Не указано'; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

А чтобы не путаться в массивах и данных, в `php` есть функции. Такие как `var_dump` и `print_r`, при помощи которых можно посмотреть структуру данных в переменной. Лично я пользуюсь `print_r` чаще. Если её написать, например `print_r($products);` и открыть исходный код, то можно будет увидеть большую структуру со вложенностями. Если не хочется исходный код открывать, можно написать

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($some_variable);
echo '</pre>';
```

Тогда прямо на странице можно будет это увидеть. Очень советую.

`var_dump` -  отображает структурированную информацию об одном или нескольких выражениях, включая их тип и значение.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает

Comment: @Arcadiy Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Алексей спасибо, подскажите пожалуйста из station каким образом вытащить значение title вместо вот этого, который вы написали <td>
                Город прибытия
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $schedule['thread']['title']; ?>
            </td>

Comment: И сразу две ошибки  $schedule['except_days'] если 0 то будет 'не указано' хотя в полне вероятно ситуация с 0. И вторая    <?=  ?> шорт теги они по умолчанию отключены и это аадки сложно дебажить. Т.К. по сути всё работает а что то невыводиться.

Comment: А как подправить и как из station взять значение title? Буду благодарен.

Comment: @Naumov `except_days` не может быть ноль, если это действительно "Кроме дней" а не что-то еще. `<?= ?>` с версии 5.4 всегда доступны. Так что это зависит от версии.. Или вы предлагаете предусмотреть все варианты для всех версий `php`?

Comment: @Arcadiy `$products['station']['title']`

Comment: @Arcadiy Если `$schedule['except_days']` действительно будет подразумевать то, что там может прийти значение `0`, тогда можно заменить `<?= $schedule['except_days'] ? $schedule['except_days'] : 'Не указано'; ?>` на `<?= (!!$schedule['except_days']) ? $schedule['except_days'] : 'Не указано'; ?>` ... а вообще это я для примера написал. Всё зависит от того, какая логика вам нужна. Может если пустое значение - то вообще вам не надо отображать строку. А может что-то писать, а может еще что-то... от потребностей зависит

Comment: Вот документация https://tech.yandex.ru/rasp/doc/reference/list-stations-route-docpage/

Comment: @Arcadiy ну вы сами можете посмотреть. `Тип
Строка`. Значит с ней можно вытворять то, что я написал в ответе. Если бы было `Тип
Число` и притом возвращаемой значение могло быть `0`, то можно было сделать так, как я написал в комментарии.... Так что господин @Naumov зря панику разводит раньше времени